# Parse and traverse client-side code in C#

Tags: user-interface, browser, automated-tests

I want to write automated tests for our website. My initial idea is to write some code to fetch the content of our webpage from our server and ensure the content is as we expect. However, to do this, I need to be able to parse and traverse HTML document in my C# code. So I am wondering whether there is a way to use Chrome's or Firefox's engines as a C# library?

Obviously, if you have better ideas for automating UI functionality testing, I am happy to hear them :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Coded UI test from within Visual Studio that is best suited for automating UI testing, but a costly one as you need valid VS license